# setxkbmap command and set local keyboard

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Suppose the following code of shell:

```
setxkbmap us ## set keyboard layout to English language
## OR 
setxkbmap ir ## set keyboard layout to Persian language
### OR
setxkbmap ru ## set keyboard layout to Russian language
```

I need to set only my keyboard layout for my one program , Suppose i'm wroking with `iceweasel` program  and run `setxkbmap ir` ....

Question is , How can i tell `setxkbdmap` to consider for one program not globally?

Comment: For those still needing this; you can use **kbdd**. https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=kbdd Simply run it just before `setxkbmap ...` in a startup file like `~/.xsessionrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://sourceforge.net/projects/perwindowlayout/. I tried and it works well for me on fluxbox. It makes advantage of `grp` option:

```
grp                  Key(s) to change layout
```

In example http://sourceforge.net/projects/perwindowlayout/files `setxkbmap` is used like this:

> setxkbmap -layout 'us,ru(winkeys)' -model pc105 -option
>   grp:rwin_toggle,grp_led:num

That means that right Win key (also known as ***super*** key) is used to change layout from `us` to `ru`. When `perwindowlayout`is started after doing that pressing right Win key would change keyboard layout only in the active window.

Comment: It's good idea, But i need a with sexkbdmap patameter, without any 3rd party. Do you know same solution?

Comment: It is not possible to do this only with `setxkbmap` unless you know how to program and are willing to modify `setxkbmap` source code. `setxkbmap` changes keyboard layout in all programs connected to the running X server, period.

Comment: If you don't want want to install any external programs check if your window manager of choice can execute an arbitrary hook when focus is changed and write a script that changes keyboard layout basing on a window title